# divergence $\{a_n + b_n\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

## Question:

Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ converges and suppose that $\{b_n\}$ diverges. Prove that
the sequence $\{a_n + b_n\}$ diverges. Hint : try a proof by contradiction

## Solution:

I don't know how I do this by contradiction.

Attempt:

Assume $\{a_n + b_n\}$ converges.

WTS: $\exists L \in \mathbb R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N$, then $|(a_n+b_n) - L| < \epsilon$

let $\epsilon = 1$

let $a_n = 1$, let $b_n = (-1)^n$

So $\exists N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, $n > N \Rightarrow |1 + (-1)^n - L| < 1$

n is odd, If $n > N$, then $|1+(-1) - L| < 1$

$$\Leftrightarrow -1 < L < 1$$

n is even, if $n > N$, then $|2-L| < 1$

$$1 < L < 3$$

Thus $L \in (-1, 1)$ and $L \in (1,3)$ A contradiction

Therefore $\{a_n + b_n\}$ diverges.

Is this a good enough proof?

Comment: You  should conduct the process generally instead of just give a counterexample.

Comment: I didnt just give a counter example, I proved the counter example. I unno

Comment: This is a proof that *your* case of $a_n,b_n$ diverges, but not in general. If $a_n$ converges, what does that tell us?

Comment: How to general?

Comment: You cannot assume values for a_n and b_n. You need to find a contradiction that is valid for any converging a_n and any diverging b_n.

Comment: If you want to obtain a contradiction, what you should do may be: With the assumption that $\{a_n\}$ converges, suppose $\{a_n+b_n\}$ converges and get the result that $\{b_n\}$ also converges.

Comment: $a_n = 1$, converges and $b_n = (-1)^n$ diverges.

Comment: Proofs by contradiction are bad habits; try a proof by contrapositive. That is, prove that if $a_n + b_n$ converges, then it cannot be the case that $a_n$ converges but $b_n$ diverges. Equivalently: prove that if $a_n + b_n$ converges and $a_n$ converges, then $b_n$ converges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By contradiction:

Suppose that $\{a_n+b_n\}$ converges and, by hypothesis, $\{a_n\}$ converges, then, $\{-a_n\}$ converges. The sum of two convergent sequences is also convergent. Then, $\{a_n+b_n\}+\{-a_n\}=\{b_n\}$ converges, but, this is a contradicition.